# 2000s~ Picture book about 2 kids who build a spaceship and travel the solar system

Tags: story-identification

Children’s book about two kids who make their own rocket and head to space.

The book often had a hollowed out diagram of the rocket so you could see all the stuff the kids built, as well as the details inside each room (such as the showers, and their space suits). The main protagonists I believe were a white boy, a black girl, and a dog. They visit each planet in the solar system, as well as the sun (where they had to wear sunglasses). I remember they also went to visit Pluto, but quickly returned because it was so cold. The rocket was red and white, and the book heavily focused on the fact that the rocket was home-made (perhaps powered by sugar?)

Any help would be so appreciated! I was really hoping someone would remember it from childhood or elementary school.